# Clonefish validation vs code igniter's validation

Tags: php, codeigniter

What are your thoughts on clonefish's validation class compared to codeigniters default validation class.

Devan

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about clonefish validation but my advise is to work inside-out. If the CI validation meets your needs, use that. Only if a 3rd party plugin offers significant advantages to you that you actually use, go with that option.